# Is there such a thing as a wildcard for boolean value?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, wildcard, jpql

I have a JPA Repository with a few custom queries.  I've been tasked with implementing a functionality which requires numerous new queries. One thing that would drastically cut down on the number of them is if I could use a wildcard for a boolean value.

I have tried modifying the query to use 'LIKE %' but Spring Data doesn't like it, throwing a numberFormatException (Infinite of NaN).

The original query:

```
 @Query("SELECT SUM(paymentSummary.paidAmount) FROM InvoiceLineItem invoice INNER JOIN PaymentSummary paymentSummary"
    + " ON invoice.invoiceKey=paymentSummary.invoiceKey"
    + " WHERE invoice.balanced=:balanced")
BigDecimal getInvoicePaidTotalByBalanced(@Param("balanced") boolean balanced);
```

Ideally, I'd like to use the same query, but instead of passing it true or false, I'd pass it a wildcard so that it acted on all records regardless of the true/false status.

As of now, the only way I know how to do this is to create a second query, same as the first, minus the where clause.

Comment: Like is only for strings, so I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `IN` operator instead? `(TRUE, FALSE)` will then be your wildcard.

Alternatively, you should be able to use `WHERE :balanced IS NULL OR invoice.balanced=:balanced`. In that case, change `boolean` to `Boolean` and `null` becomes the wildcard.